# creating a leaderboard in firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I had a function which successfully queried a child node called /mobile_user and ranked the top 10 users based on the value on "earned_points" and also wrote those top 10 users to a new node called /leaderboard which is on the same level as /mobile_user

I switched to firestore because i want to use the powerful queries and i;m unable to change the syntax from firebase rtdb to firestore

My function looks like this

```
 exports.leaderboardUpdate2 = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) =>{
  const updates = [];
  const leaderboard = {};

  const ref = admin.firestore().collection('mobile_user');
  const leaderboardRef = admin.firestore().collection('/leaderboard');

  return ref.orderBy("earned_points").limit(10).get().then(dataSnapshot => {
      let i = 0;
      dataSnapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        const r = dataSnapshot.data.count() - i;
        console.log(r)
        updates.push(childSnapshot.ref.update({rank: r}));
        leaderboard[childSnapshot.key] = Object.assign(childSnapshot.val(), {rank: r});
        i++;
      });

      updates.push(leaderboardRef.set(leaderboard));
      return Promise.all(updates);
    }).then(() => {
      res.status(200).send("Mobile user ranks updated");
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.error(err);
      res.status(500).send("Error updating ranks.");
    });
});
```

I've been stuck for hours trying to get the count of the snapshot and then iterating to add a rank.

Any help or advice is appreciated

Comment: you can get some of the logic by a Firebase video launched today at FCM talk at Firebase Summit, check it out https://youtu.be/c66gQzNNHuA?t=899